# I have Type Errors like only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, numpy

When I tried to import complex number in my code I have the following error: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
import os

# Create target Directory if don't exist

if not os.path.exists('Sparameters images'):
    os.mkdir('Sparameters images')

## UPLOAD DATA ##############################
#############################################

HB1 = np.loadtxt('S11_Magnitude\S11_Magnitude.txt',skiprows=7)
HB2 = np.loadtxt('S11_Phase\S11_Phase.txt',skiprows=7)
HB3 = np.loadtxt('S21_Magnitude\S12_Magnitude.txt',skiprows=7)
HB4 = np.loadtxt('S21_Phase\S12_Phase_Width.txt',skiprows=7)

## CONVERT DATA TO LINEAR MAGNITUDE AND RADS #####################
##################################################################

W1=HB1[:,0]
A_mag=np.power(10,HB1[:,1]/10)*100
W2=HB2[:,0]
A_Phase=HB2[:,1]
W3=HB3[:,0]
B_mag=np.power(10,HB3[:,1]/10)*100
W4=HB4[:,0]
B_Phase=HB4[:,1] 

## CONVERTING INTO COMPLEX NUMBERS ##############################
#################################################################

S11 = [A_mag * math.cos(A_Phase)] + 1j * [A_mag * math.sin(A_Phase)]
S21 = [B_mag * math.cos(B_Phase)] + 1j * [B_mag * math.sin(B_Phase)]
```

I have tried many also this but it doesn't work

```
S11 = np.vectorize(complex)(A_mag * math.cos(A_Phase), A_mag * math.sin(A_Phase))
S21 = np.vectorize(complex)(B_mag * math.cos(B_Phase), B_mag * math.sin(B_Phase))
```

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This has nothing to do with [tag:spyder] and everything to do with [tag:numpy]. Please make sure to tag your posts properly. See [ask].

Comment: What do you mean that it has nothing to do with spyder and python?

Comment: Spyder is just an IDE. It's irrelevant.